# Download Markers from an Embedded Google Map using Python (Slimit, BeautifulSoup, & Requests)

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps

I would like to download the markers from an embedded google map in order to find the country the marker resides in.  I did not create the map, so I can not export the KML. I tried downloading the content using requests and parsing through the HTML content using Beautiful Soup, then finding the country information by parsing the JavaScript in slimit. However this only allowed me to find a small number of the waypoints on the map. The organization operates in over 100 countries, but my search is only returning 14 country names.  I wonder if I need to use a google maps specific module?

Sample Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor

#Get HTML Content
with requests.Session() as c:
    page = c.get("http://www.ifla-world-report.org/cgi-bin/static.ifla_wr.cgi?dynamic=1&d=ifla_wr_browse&page=query&interface=map")
    pContent = page.content

#Parse through HTML and Grab the Javascript
soup = BeautifulSoup(pContent)

text_to_find = "country"

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    #Now Parse through the Javascript to find the country variable
    lookat = Parser()
    tree = lookat.parse(script.text)
    for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
            value = getattr(node.left, 'value', '')
            if text_to_find in value:
                country = getattr(node.right, 'value', '')
                print country[1:-1]
```

Comment: Maybe you should just ask them for their data (and permission to use it).  The JSON is publicly available (which doesn't mean you can use it without permission).

Comment: I would, but I have to do this on a regular basis with a variety of nonprofits who do not have the manpower to make their data available to me.  Plus the data is all ready publicly available in the form of the markers...

Comment: If you have permission, just download the JSON and write code to create markers from it.